# Can't use App.xaml resources after Dependency Injection .NET MAUI

Tags: dependency-injection, maui

I have an application that uses mvvm pattern with Community Toolkit features. I am trying to use Dependency Injection to use an ApiService with its interface in my viewmodels, but after following the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72429297/injecting-services-into-view-models-in-net-maui-app), I can't access to App.xaml Resources (specifically colors), the intellisense works when I am writing code in XAML, but it doesn´t work after running. It is important to notice that I was using colors from resources correctly before trying to use Dependency Injection and changing the ViewModel - View linking method to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72429297/injecting-services-into-view-models-in-net-maui-app), but I was unable to use ApiService.
Here is my code.

**App.xaml.cs (Login page is my first page):**

```
public App(LoginPage page)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = page;
}
```

**LoginPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
  public LoginPage(LoginPageViewModel loginPageViewModel)
  {
    BindingContext = loginPageViewModel;
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

**LoginPageViewModel**

```
public LoginPageViewModel(IApiService apiService)
    {
        _apiService = apiService;
        Opacity = 1f;
        IsEnabled = true;
        IsRunning = false;
    }
```

**LoginPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="NewScholarApp.Views.LoginPage"
         Title="LoginPage"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:NewScholarApp.ViewModels"
         x:DataType="vm:LoginPageViewModel"
         BackgroundColor="{StaticResource GreenSchool}">
```

**MauiProgam.cs**

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>().UseMauiCommunityToolkit().ConfigureViewModels().ConfigureServices().ConfigureViews()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        });

    //builder.Services.AddSingleton<ApiService>();

    return builder.Build();
}
```

**RegisterViews and ViewModels**

```
public static MauiAppBuilder ConfigureViews(this MauiAppBuilder mauiAppBuilder)
    {
        mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddTransient<LoginPage>();

        return mauiAppBuilder;
    }

public static class RegisterViewModels
{

    public static MauiAppBuilder ConfigureViewModels(this MauiAppBuilder mauiAppBuilder)

    {
        mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<LoginPageViewModel>();

        return mauiAppBuilder;
    }
}
```

Open issue: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11485

Comment: Could you share more code of LoginPage.xaml and how do you register your views and viewmodels?

Comment: your _api service it's like this?         private IApiService _apiService { get; set; } on your LoginPageViewModel?

Comment: Shaw: I added the code where I register the views and viewmodels to the original question. Leandro Toloza: No, I just declared like this: private readonly IApiService _apiService; but actually, I don't have problems using the ApiService, my problem is that I am unable to access to App.xaml resources.

Answer (score 0):

This question is related to [Cannot use StaticResources for resources in App.xaml](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3878). IndianaGary's comment indicated that you could try a **DynamicResource**.

Comment: Right, but that issue was created since december 2021 in preview versions of MAUI, isn't there a solution yet?

Comment: I've also reproduced the issue with your steps and you could create an issue on GitHub.