# net maui: Cannot dynamically create an instance of type ''. Reason: No parameterless constructor defined

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, maui

when I click on the button to go to the page, an exception appears " System.MissingMethodException: "It is not possible to dynamically create an instance of the type 'MuseumFinder.Views.The museum list page for administrators". Reason: The constructor without parameters is not defined."

But I do not know how to fix it so that the view displays the result of the viewmodel and at the same time the transition to the page is carried out.

```
 private async void OnCounterClicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await AppShell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(MuseumListPageForAdmins));
    }
```

```
using MuseumFinder.ViewModels;

namespace MuseumFinder.Views;

public partial class MuseumListPageForAdmins : ContentPage
{
   

    private MuseumListPageViewModel _viewModel;
    public MuseumListPageForAdmins(MuseumListPageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        this.BindingContext = viewModel;

    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        _viewModel.GetMuseumListCommand.Execute(null);

    }
```

```
 private readonly IMuseumService _museumService;
        public MuseumListPageViewModel(IMuseumService museumService)
        {
            _museumService = museumService;
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Injecting services into view models in .NET MAUI app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72429297/injecting-services-into-view-models-in-net-maui-app). Despite the different title, that question is about the same error, "no parameterless constructor". The accepted answer shows what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The way your using it now looks like some Dependency Injection style, I haven't used before.

Appshell needs a parameterless constructor to create a new view. Since the routing is not passing any parameters, you don't need to specify the ViewModel in the constructor

Try the following code

```
using MuseumFinder.ViewModels;

namespace MuseumFinder.Views;

public partial class MuseumListPageForAdmins : ContentPage
{
   

    private MuseumListPageViewModel _viewModel = new();
    public MuseumListPageForAdmins()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _viewModel;
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        _viewModel.GetMuseumListCommand.Execute(null);

    }
```

I've changed so the view makes a new instance of the viewmodel on creation and sets the BindingContexts to it.

EDIT: Remember the InitializeComponent() function to render the controls of the view. Nearly forgot it myself in the answer ;)

Comment: But now I do not know what to do with my view model constructor. I added the code to the question, please take a look.

Comment: @JohnB take a look at this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72429297/injecting-services-into-view-models-in-net-maui-app seems to have the answer you are looking for

Comment: *"Appshell needs a parameterless constructor to create a new view."* If using DI, this is not true. As shown in Gerald's answer you link.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I'll review and update my answer. Didn't know about dependency injection in MAUI. And educate myself a little on the topic.