# .NET MAUI register services of type IRootObjectProvider and IProvideValueTarget

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, maui

I am playing around with NET MAUI and find myself at a point where I am out of idea.

I am trying to write some validation library and I got stuck.

```
    private void Validate()
    {
        var serviceProvider = this.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetService<IServiceProvider>();

        var root = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRootObjectProvider>()
                  .RootObject as BindableObject;

        var targetObject = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IProvideValueTarget>()
            .TargetObject as BindableObject;
    }
```

Runing this code I got an error that IRootObjectProvider and the IProvideValueTarget are not registered in the DI. I can't find any documentation that should help resolve this, or this happens sometimes automatically.

A little digging got me to find that I need in the DI container the following:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IProvideValueTarget, XamlValueTargetProvider>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IRootObjectProvider, XamlRootObjectProvider>();
```

Then I got in another problem XamlValueTargetProvider and XamlRootObjectProvider are internal classes.

So, I am wondering how these instances can be injected thru ID.

Another interesting part that I found a code, where a class implements the `IMarkupExtension<BindingBase> => BindingBase IMarkupExtension<BindingBase>.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)` interface then the serviceprovider has those two clases registered in the DI container.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find any documentation that should help resolve this, or this happens sometimes automatically.

About how to use DI in .NET MAUI you can refer to the official doc: [Dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection). Microsoft puts it here instead of in the [MAUI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/?view=net-maui-7.0)...

In addition, you can also see these cases: [thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72429297/injecting-services-into-view-models-in-net-maui-app) | [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72438903/how-can-i-resolve-a-service-that-i-registered-with-the-builder-services-inside-o).

Wish it can help you.

Comment: I know how DI works. I need those two interfaces in DI pool, but manually I can't do it because those two classes are internal, so I can't add them in DI pool.

Comment: *because those two classes are internal,* Could you set them to public?

Comment: no I cant, because they are built in classes in .net maui

Comment: *because they are built in classes in .net maui* I'm afraid they can't add them to the DI pool